# How Can I Return Navigate at UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to use react at my project. But I' m getting error like "useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned: [object Object]". How can I navigate user to Home component? Can you give me an idea?

Login/index.js

```html
const Login = (props) => {
          const [errors,setErrors] = useState([]);
          const [error,setError] = useState(null);

          useEffect(() => {
              if(props.AuthStore.appState != null){
                  if(props.AuthStore.appState.isLoggedIn){
                      return <Navigate to={{pathname:'/'}} />
                  }
              }
 },[]);

 const _handleSubmit = async(values, {setSubmitting})=>{
            await axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/auth/login`, {
                    ...values
            }).then(async (result) => {
                const userData = {
                    ...result.data
                };
                const appState = {
                    isLoggedIn:true,
                    user:userData
                }
                await props.AuthStore.save(appState);
                window.location.reload();
  })
            .catch((error)=>{
             console.log(error.response);
            })
    }
```

PrivateRoute.js

```html
AuthStore.get();
const isLoggedIn = AuthStore.appstate != null && AuthStore.appstate.isLoggedIn;

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component }) => {
    return isLoggedIn  ? <Component /> : <Navigate to={{pathname:'/login'}} /> ;
}
```

AppRoutes.js

```html
const AppRoutes = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
       props.AuthStore.get()
    }, [])
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Fallback</div>}>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute component={Home} />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="/support" element={<Support />} />
        </Routes>
        </Suspense>
    );
};
```

Comment: This line is the problem `return <Navigate to={{pathname:'/'}} />` inside useEffect. Use useNavigate hook to reroute

Answer (score 1):

You can try `useNavigate()` , it will look like this in your case.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";    
const Login = (props) => {
      const navigate = useNavigate()
      const [errors,setErrors] = useState([]);
      const [error,setError] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
          if(props.AuthStore.appState != null){
              if(props.AuthStore.appState.isLoggedIn){
                 navigate('/')
              }
          }
 },[]);
```